# BIG QUERY SQL: How to find different sets of duplicates within a visit with same unique keys but different period of the visit?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

**WHAT IS THIS POST FOR?**

In bigquery, I need to remove duplicated rows with a **caveat**

*that duplication happened within the same visit for a visitor for page visits with the same pagename.*

GROUP BY DOES NOT RESOLVE THE ISSUE

Below,I have explained the data, issue, possible resolution and measure taken to the best of my ability.

**WHAT DATA AM I USING?**

Adobe data imported to Bigquery ( no issues in importing )

Each row is the data collected by page-view for a visitor.

Each time a visitor moves to new page it counts a visit_page_num + 1 in the same visit_num and for same visitor_id.

The pagename is recorded for each page visited.

**ISSUE :**

In this image,

[image]

some of the visit_page_num are **counted as unique** on unique visitor_id, visit_num but are **duplicated** as the pagename is same.

```
ISSUE
visit_page_num      pagename
       1               a
       2               b
       3               c  -issue
       4               c  -issue
       5               d
       6               d
       7               d
       8               e
       9               c  -issue
      10               c  -issue
      11               c  -issue 


Solution so far with GROUP BY
visit_page_num      pagename
       1               a
       2               b
       3               c  -issue
       5               d
       8               e


  GOAL
visit_page_num      pagename
       1               a
       2               b
       3               c  -Goal
       5               d
       8               e
       9               c  -Goal
```

When duplicates on same pagename occur but at different time in the visit then how ***do we insure the later duplication are not eliminated but counted as different page visit***.

**QUERY USED :**

```
SELECT visitor_id
,visit_num
,pagename
,first (visit_page_num) AS first
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY visitor_id, visit_num ORDER BY visitor_id, visit_num, pagename) AS int_var
FROM [table] 
GROUP BY visitor_id, visit_num, pagename
ORDER BY visitor_id, visit_num, first
```

**OUTPUT :**

Everything is Good **EXCEPT** the,

[image]

visitor_id = A on visit_num = 1 and pagename = c

**ACTIONS TAKEN :**

1. I have tried the LEAD and LAG function with MIN and MAX function in second step>>> SAME OUTPUT
2. CHECKED the web, normal SQL functions that can be translated into BIGQUERY >> SAME OUTPUT
3. Asked my team lead >> SAME OUTPUT
4. 5 hours of experimenting >> SAME OUTPUT

**CAVEAT**

Cannot use field_date OR any time field OR any other field beside the one mentioned in the table

Comment: in future could you please include sample data in a reusable format (not as an image)

Comment: Sure, I apologize I am not yet aware how to do that. Can you send a link or manual how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: just use the code block shown as `{ }`  in the toolbar above a comment or look for help in the footer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try locating only the transitions between pages e.g.

```
SELECT
    visitor_id
  , visit_num
  , pagename
FROM (
    select
    *
    , lead(pagename) over(partition by visitorid order by visit_page_num)
      as nxt_page
    from table1
    ) derived
WHERE nxt_page <> pagename or nxt_page IS NULL
ORDER BY visitor_id, visit_num
```

Comment: Thanks @Used_By_Already , I tried the lag and lead together going down the visit. Thanks for showing that going up the visit would have been a time saver!!! Appreciate your help very much. :)

Comment: going up or down doesn't really matter, what does matter is filtering on only the page transitions.